# Cannot connect to wss://ip:5063 when deploy restcomm docker to public server

Tags: docker, restcomm

I am new to restcomm, and just followed the get started guide to set up the docker, but found out the websocket connection cannot be established.

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://mydomainname:5063/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
WSMessageChannel.createWebSocket @ jain-sip.js:25448
jain-sip.js:25466 WSMessageChannel:createWebSocket(): websocket connection has failed:[object Event]
websocket.onerror @ jain-sip.js:25466
WebRTComm.js:1561  PrivateJainSipClientConnector:processConnectionError(): SIP connection has failed, error:[object Event]
```

And I checked the port using lsof -i TCP:5063, the port is listened

```
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
docker-pr 10420 root    4u  IPv6 5902547      0t0  TCP *:5063 (LISTEN)
```

and when I issue `docker ps`, I got

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                                                                                                                                                            NAMES
263bad288971        restcomm/restcomm:stable   "/sbin/my_init"     10 hours ago        Up 10 hours         0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, 5080-5083/tcp, 8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5060-5063->5060-5063/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5060->5060/udp, 5080/udp, 0.0.0.0:9990->9990/tcp, 0.0.0.0:65000-65050->65000-65050/udp, 8443/tcp, 65051-65535/udp   restcomm-myInstance
```

I have tried set STATIC_ADDRESS to both public IP and ethernet IP, but it did not work. Anyone can help me out?

Comment: @NehalJWani yes，0.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

I found out the reason, my cloud provider blocks some ports and it works when I open these ports